# c++ WWSAPI how to write date without time to WS_DATETIME

Tags: c++, web-services, xsd, wwsapi

i have a problem with sending message to WebService

I'm generating code with wsutil.exe, in wsdl and xsd files i have field marked as xsd:date (only date), wsutil.exe generate's this properties as WS_DATETIME.

I can't send message to WebService becouse i have error about invalid date format. For test i have changed xsd:date to xsd:datetime and it all works, but i can't do this on original xsd file.

I'm creating WS_DATETIME from COleDateTime by converting it to SYSTEMTIME next FILETIME and finally using method WsFileTimeToDateTime.

Is there a way to create WS_DATETIME without time or can i use some other way to send date without time to my WebService ?